# IE11 Compatibility issue on windows

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have a html page where I have 3 framesets. One frameset contains an attachment. The application works fine in IE8. But when I click the button that opens the html page with the 3 framesets in IE11 the attachment is detached from the pane and is shown as an individual tab. I tried adding the  tag in my html page in the  tag. But it still isn't working. When I change the compatibility mode from developer tools(F12) in IE11, the application is working fine. By default the compatibility mode is set to F5. The user cannot always change the compatibility mode from internet explorer. So, I want the compatibility mode to be set to "Edge" by default to IE11. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Google `X-UA-Compatible`

Comment: @Pointy If only it was that simple.

Comment: @MrLister well that's certainly what you'd do to force IE away from compatibility mode (assuming the page is otherwise not going to induce quirks mode of course). Note that the OP says that when the browser is set back to IE11 via the dev tools, it works.

Comment: @Pointy I added the tag <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/> in my html page right after <html> tag and before <head>tag. It still isn't woking

Comment: Does your page have a proper `<DOCTYPE>` etc? You haven't posted any code at all so it's hard to help.

Comment: <HTML><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/><HEAD><TITLE>Attachmate Extra</TITLE>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var timerID;
var initTime = 0;
//var EIMSApp = "https://e-web1dev.mcds.caxix.hcg.eds.com/EIMSGetImage/EIMSGet?logonRoleID=dcal&server=DEAD&folder=E-ALL-DOCS&Key=";
//var edsEIMSApp = "https://e-web1test.mcds.caxix.hcg.eds.com/EIMSGetImage/EIMSGet?logonRoleID=dcal&server=DEAS&folder=E-ALL-DOCS&Key=";
//var EIMSApp = "https://e-web1test.eds.delta.org/EIMSGetImage/EIMSGet?logonRoleID=dcal&server=DEAS&folder=E-ALL-DOCS&Key=";

Comment: @Pointy Well! There is no DOCTYPE in my code. My code starts as shown in the comment I posted above. The X-UA tag is what I added. The rest is already established code

Comment: Without a `<DOCTYPE>` you're probably putting the browser in quirks mode. Try  adding at least `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the very top.

Comment: @PointyMy servers are down right now. If adding<!DOCTYPE html> works, you are a life saver. fingers crossed!